# create a link list of integer numbers it will split the list into two different lists of odd and even numbers and display the resultant

Tags: singly-linked-list

We need to create a singly linked list then seperate the odd and even values into a even and odd singly linked list. I may be able to explain it but I am facing difficulty in figuring out the exact code.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I have made a function print and then tried to check which values are odd or even in the original list. Upto that is fine but after that I can't insert those into even and odd linked list.

Comment: That's a good starting point. First and foremost you must instantiate two empty lists "evens" and "odds" While you are traversing your list, checking for odd and evens, you can simultaneously append the items to their respective lists. For example if number is odd, append  to "odds", and do the same for the evens.